# Numerator and denominator separated by hyphen

Tags: notation, math-history

This is a question about historical notation practices.

A colleague recently sent me a scan of a portion of a 1935 paper:

> P. R. Bassett.  "[Passenger Comfort in Air Transportation](http://arc.aiaa.org/doi/abs/10.2514/8.78?journalCode=jans)", Journal of the Aeronautical Sciences (Institute of the Aeronautical Sciences), Vol. 2, No. 2 (1935), pp. 48–50.

He asked me to guess what was meant here, particularly by the "1-10" notation:

[image]

After considering carefully, I guessed that the “1-10g” actually meant $\frac1{10}g$, where $g$ is the [acceleration due to the Earth's gravity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_acceleration#Gravity_model_For_Earth), a fairly common unit of acceleration in this kind of context, and that the following “1-10” similarly meant $\frac1{10}$.

This would mean that the hyphen was being used to separate the numerator and denominator of the fraction $\frac1{10}$.  I vaguely remember having seen this before, but can't think of any examples.

My question is about the rarity and usage patterns of this notation.  Is it a one-off oddity, or was it ever usual?  If it was a usual notation, how common was it, during what period was it most widely used, and by whom?  Was it more common in certain sorts of literature, or at certain times?

I looked briefly in Cajori 1928, especially §272–275, which discuss the introduction of the “$1/10$” notation, but I was not able to find anything relevant.

Comment: I've seen $1:10$ and $1 ; 10$ (common in Europe) to denote fractions.

Comment: I wonder whether it was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the use of dash is that it is used to separate two connected numbers, such as hours-minutes or stones-pounds.  One would write a weight as 8-7, meaning eight-stones, seven pounds.  There was a show called the 6-5 show (ie 5 minutes after 6pm).

I have seen things like 5-8 (five-eight), meaning five-eights, but i can't recall where.

Some of the more ancient texts i have from C19, certianly know of the solidus for division, money amounts tend to be spaced (a solidus is a shilling), or evident by context.

Like the long hundred, it tends to fly below the radar of the learned.